# Entry in USA and then onto Canada

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, canada, driving, esta

I’m a bit confused about entry into the USA. I’m flying to Boston from the UK for a long weekend and meeting Canadian relatives there. We were then hoping to drive across to Canada and then I would Fly back to the UK from Toronto. I understand that you have to apply for ESTA and also the Canadian equivalent.

My question is: at US immigration would I satisfy the authorities that I have satisfactory travel arrangements to gain entry into the US? Also, would I be allowed to travel across the border by private transport? My flights have been booked.

Comment: You do not need a Canadian eTA to cross the land border.

Comment: Yes, you can cross the boarder by private transport.

Answer (score 2):

As phoog mentions, an eTA is not required when [entering by land](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/entry-requirements-country.html). This lists countries exempt from the eTA .

Comment: But what about the round-trip ticket requirement for the VWP? Can a ticket from Canada to the UK fulfill this requirement?